# How to securely store database credentials in windows?

Tags: python, sql-server, windows, pymssql, database-security

I use python and SQL-server to manage a database, but I do not know "good practices" about database management and know few about security information.

Is it secure to save Database credentials in Windows as a environment variable and use it into scripts with `os.environ`? Like this:

```
import os
DB_HOST = os.environ['DBHOST']
DB_USER = os.environ['DBUSER']
...
```

How is the proper way to store credentials to automate uses of databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking if you should permanently set environment variables for your laptop - I’d avoid that because any process could list **all** environment variables on the PC and the associated stored values quite easily.

Instead - I’d recommend checking out [Keyring](https://pypi.org/project/keyring/). This will use the Windows Credential Locker (or other OS specific keyring services).

Answer (score 1):

Usually secure credentials are stored in a .env file that relates to your current environment and then are grabbed from within your code. E.g DB_HOST = env('DBHOST').

Basically what you're doing right now but stored in a file (as secure as you need it, possibly encrypted) rather than directly as environment variables as they're accessible from the entire machine.

Answer (score 1):

By using Encryptedbypassphrase('key','Your_Password') method in sqlserver,
Example,

`create table #temp(id int identity(1,1),Password varbinary(max))
    insert into #temp(Password) values(encryptbypassphrase('12','Passw0rd'))
    select * from #temp`

> In that code we are provide the original password but it stored in the database 
>   table by encrypted value.

Screenshot of my output:

[image: For your ref Screenshot of my output is below,]